# (Django) save(*args, **kwargs) vs. save(**kwargs)

Tags: django, django-models

When I searched for overriding the save method I found to different things:

```
def save(self, **kwargs):
  pass
```

and:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
  pass
```

What's better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save(self, *args, **kwargs) is the recommended way to go since it is the signature you can find in the django source code

Edit:
I am assuming you are talking about the save() method in case of django models